# Error when running torch prediction model on GPU

Tags: lua, dockerfile, cudnn

I have been trying to use a specific pretrained machine learning model for captioning pictures. I have been using https://github.com/unnonouno/densecap .

It comes with a Dockerfile setting up a whole cuda/torch/cudnn environement.

Predictions on a new picture are made by running the `run_model.lua` script. It does work when running it on the CPU by passing `-gpu -1` but not when removing the arguement and running it on the GPU. I get the following error in that case:

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-8398/cutorch/lib/THC/THCGeneral.c line=70 error=35 : CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
/root/torch/install/bin/luajit: 
/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: loop or previous error loading module 'cutorch'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
    ./densecap/utils.lua:26: in function 'setup_gpus'
    run_model.lua:145: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    /root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

I have tried different things such as reinstalling `cudnn` by runnign `luarocks install cudnn` or downgrading from `cudnn5` to `cudnn4` without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be with your CUDA driver:

> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Take a look at similar discussions [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1028320/cuda-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-runtime-version/).

No need to change your cuDNN version. You just need to rectify your CUDA driver/toolkit compatibility.